# jade outputs relative links

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, express, templating, pug

I'm starting to play with node, express and jade and when I do this

```
a(href="http:/www.example.com/" + variable) variable
```

I get a relative link, say

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/www.example.com/mytext">mytext</a>
```

Instead of the absolute link.

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the enviroment stuff, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you noticed that you have only *ONE* slash in your `http:/` protocol.  You need two.

I didn't think jade did any processing whatsoever of those attributes, once computed. Actually, with jade 0.12.4, I can't reproduce your behavior. Jade outputs `<a href="http:/www.example.com/mytext">variable</a>'. Note that the second instance of`variable` is a string literal, not interpreted javascript code (this is by design). You want

```
a(href="http://www.example.com/" + variable)= variable
```

to get your desired output.

Try updating to the latest jade to be sure, but I doubt jade is the issue.

My guess is jade is actually outputting the raw HTML correctly and that you are looking at the URL in your browser's status bar when you mouseover the link?  Maybe the browser is doing that conversion to an absolute URL due to your missing slash?

Comment: You're absolutely right, didn't know about the = thing, I was doing {#variable} instead thanks!